# How do I use my GPU to accelerate video encoding?

Tags: windows, video, gpu, video-encoding

I have an ATI Radeon HD 4870 graphics card. I have read that I can use this to significantly speed up encoding DVD to AVI.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ATI Catalyst drivers now come with the [Avivo video converter](http://ati.amd.com/technology/Avivo/technology.html). This should do what you're looking for, though I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at [ATI Stream Technology](http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/TECHNOLOGIES/STREAM-TECHNOLOGY/Pages/stream-technology.aspx) if you want to being able to really gain **significant speed** increment in encoding/decoding videos. That is the ATI answer to [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html) from NVidia.

Both technologies aim to allow software developers to program GPU ([GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpgpu)) to increase the performances of their applications.

Here it is the ATI [web page](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/stream-technology/consumer/Pages/entertainment.aspx) that describe how **ATI Stream** could accelerate the digital home entertainment.

I hope we will see many SW in feature that will use more our GPU also when we are not playing :D